# AChartEngine getIntent() display point values

Tags: java, android, android-intent, achartengine

I am using the AChartEngine library in my application. I currently am calculating the data points in a thread and displaying the graph upon completion. I am using the getIntent() method as I run different calculations based on which button the user selects. I want to be able to allow the user to select a point on the completed graph and have it display the values at that point. Is there a way to use the onClickListener with the intent? Or another way to possibly do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `GraphicalView` approach. Doing this will allow you to easily add a click listener on the chart. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) example for some code.